# Changing color of whole row in a table when a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

How do I change the color of a whole row in a table when a condition is met?

For example, FAILURE is returned? Make the whole row RED.

```
<tr> <!-- Disk Space Available -->
                <td class="tg-yw4l">ld</td>
                <td class="tg-yw4l">
                <?php 
                    if ($ld_status == 0) {
                        echo 'SUCCESS';
                    } else if ($ld_status == 1) {
                        echo 'WARNING';
                    } else {
                        echo 'FAILURE';
                    }   
                ?>
                </td>
```

Comment: Use the bgcolor attribute of the `<tr>` tag.

Comment: @DanBracuk [Even W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_tr_bgcolor.asp) (not exactly known for being ahead of the curve) caution against using the `bgcolor` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the class of the tr with PHP, then in the css you can change the style of each class.

**CSS**

```
.success{
  background-color: green;
  }

.warning{
  background-color: yellow;
  }

.failure{
  background-color: red;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class=" <?php 
                    if ($ld_status == 0) {
                        echo 'success';
                    } else if ($ld_status == 1) {
                        echo 'warning';
                    } else {
                        echo 'failure';
                    }   
                ?>"> 

                <td class="tg-yw4l">ld</td>
                <td class="tg-yw4l">
                <?php 
                    if ($ld_status == 0) {
                        echo 'SUCCESS';
                    } else if ($ld_status == 1) {
                        echo 'WARNING';
                    } else {
                        echo 'FAILURE';
                    }   
                ?>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This it will be work proper for your condition

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <?php $ld_status=2; ?>
    <table border="1">
    <tr style="background:<?php if($ld_status == 0) { echo 'green'; } else if ($ld_status == 1){ echo 'yellow';  } else { echo 'red';}?>;" > <!-- Disk Space Available -->
                    <td class="tg-yw4l">ld</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l">
                    <?php 
                        if ($ld_status == 0) {
                            echo 'SUCCESS';
                        } else if ($ld_status == 1) {
                            echo 'WARNING';
                        } else {
                            echo 'FAILURE';
                        }   
                    ?>
                    </td>
            </table>        
    </html>
```